# PHP - Concatenating 2 objects

Tags: php

I have 2 objects.

Here is the output of the objects when I print them out with `print_r` method of the PHP.

Oject #1;

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [portal_id] => 1 [name=> NEVZAT )
```

Object #2;

```
stdClass Object ( [surname] => YILMAZ)
```

I want to concatenate these 2 objects to each other so at the end of the process I need an Object which contains all of the variables of the 2 objects;

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [portal_id] => 1 [name=> NEVZAT [surname] => YILMAZ )
```

Comment: first use google. then stackoverflow.

Comment: This question has already asked here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A simple way would be to temporarily cast the objects to arrays, merge those arrays, then case the resulting array back to a `stdClass` object.

```
$merged = (object) array_merge((array) $object_a, (array) $object_b);
```

Comment: looks OK, thank you, but I want to know if this is the only way. Because it may cause some performance issues, there are lots of type castings.

Comment: Of course it is not the **only** way.  Re. performance issues, my only advice would be to worry about performance when performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 6):

Just copy over the attributes like so:

```
// assume $o1 and $o2 are your objects
// we copy $o1 attributes to $o2
foreach ($o1 as $attr => $value) {
        $o2->{$attr} = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        class MergeObj {
            // Empty class
        }
         
        $objectA = new MergeObj();
        $objectA->a = 1;
        $objectA->b = 2;
        $objectA->d = 3;
         
        $objectB = new MergeObj();
        $objectB->d = 4;
        $objectB->e = 5;
        $objectB->f = 6;
         
        $obj_merged = (object) array_merge((array) $objectA,(array) $objectB);
                 
        print_r($obj_merged); 
?>
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [d] => 4
    [e] => 5
    [f] => 6
)
```

Demo Link: https://onecompiler.com/php/3yn3amgjv