# two columns where clause merge with comma

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to build a query.

> here is table:

```
id  user_id  sn_no
1   22       00112233
2   22       987654325
3   22       65489732
4   25       984123123
5   25       9568456456
6   25       65456456
```

I want result like this:

```
{
   "user_id":22,
   "sn_no": "00112233,987654325,65489732"
}
{
   "user_id":25,
   "sn_no": "984123123,9568456456,65456456"
}
```

Can anyone please help to solve this issue?

I have tried: `concat`, `GROUP_CONCAT` but can not get the result.

Can you please help me add this in Join query?

```
$users = \DB::table('users')
            ->join('users_mcu', 'users.id', '=', 'users_mcu.user_id')
            ->join('country_user', 'users.id', '=', 'country_user.user_id')
            ->join('country_phase_color', 'country_user.country_id', '=', 'country_phase_color.id')
            ->select('users.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'users.company', 'users.designation', 'users.lang', 'users.phone', 'users.disp_graph', 'users.user_image', 'users.email', 'users.role', 'users.created_at', 'users.updated_at', 'country_user.country_id', 'country_phase_color.country_name')
            ->get();
```

Comment: DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(sn_no SEPARATOR ',')) as `sn_no` did you use group concat like this

Comment: default `SEPARATOR`  is `','` so no need to defined it again

Comment: Please share your where you have tried GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this-

```
YourModel::select('user_id')
         ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(sn_no) as sn')
         ->groupBy('user_id')
         ->get();
```

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Actually I don't know the column name `sn_no` in which table... please be confirm about `sn_no`

Comment: sn_no is stored in user_mcu table

Comment: IT says -------users.id' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: First check with `->select('*', DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(users_mcu.sn_no SEPARATOR ',')) as sn"))`

Comment: let me explain you something in detail  : there are 4 tables users, users_mcu, country_user, country_phase_color. I want user data with country_phase_color.country_name, country_user.country_id, so this works fine for me now there is a table for users_mcu which i have mention in top of the message, where user_id is there, now i want that list in same query with comma saperated of sn_no

Comment: HI, Do you know how can i merge 2 array to 1 with same user_id

Comment: You can use `array_merge()` please see the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283532/how-to-merge-laravel-objects-in-controller . On other hand if you face any problem please create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$data = \DB::table('tablename')->select('user_id', \DB::raw('group_concat(sn_no) as sn_nos'))->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

as if you want to change `SEPARATOR` then you can use `SEPARATOR` for it otherwise the default will be `','`

```
\DB::table('tablename')->select('user_id',DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(sn_no SEPARATOR '@')) as `sn_nos`"))->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

use mysql [group_concat](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) function and laravel [groupBy and raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions)  function

```
DB::tabe('tableName')
   ->select('id','user_id',\DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(`sn_no`) as sn_no_t'))
   ->groupBy('user_id')
   ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
use DB;

DB::table('tableName')
        ->select('id','user_id','DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(sn_no SEPARATOR ',')) as `sn_nos`")')
        ->groupBy('user_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
Model::select('user_id')
       ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(sn_nos) as sn_nos')
       ->groupBy('user_id')
       ->get();
```