# How to pass multiple dataProviders to CListView

Tags: yii

I'm having some trouble trying to pass multiple dataProviders to a ClistView in Yii. What is the correct way of doing it?

I've tried:

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(


'dataProvider'=>array($dataProvider, $dataProvider2),
```

I've also had a look at this [What is the best method to merge two PHP objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects). Not sure if the best approach would be to try and do it with pure PHP or if the Framework has options for this and i've just missed them.

Appreciate any help.

thanks

Jonny

Comment: By design you can only pass one data provider to a ListView or GridView. Anything else doesn't make much sense. You should better try to get the merged data from your provider.

Comment: @MichaelHärtl Thanks Michael, you help me a lot. If you want to put this as the answer I shall mark accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situation like this, I develop my own CListView:

```
class MyClistView extends CListView{

}
```

the dataProvider is required for CListView so pass ArrayDataProvider that contains your dataproviders and Iterate them and dont forget to implement your logic for rendering.

PS: Dont forget to take a look to [CBaseListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is if you have a [relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship) between the two models. 
Then you can just output it as is in your itemView:

```
echo $data->relationItem; 

// Or if it is a HAS_MANY relation
foreach ($data->relationItems as $i)
    echo $i->something;
```

Not what you were after?

Another solution could be to iterate through your models, cherry-pick the things you want into a new array and then feed it using a [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider) to your ClistView.

Comment: Thanks Ippi. It's not quite what I'm after, these are two very different CSqlDataProvider models. I haven't seen any real answers to this so I think Michael probably summed it up the best. But thanks for this, it may be helpful to me and others.