# Yii data provider with clist view

Tags: yii

i want to search multiple models in Yii application. The search result are displayed in CList view. Need to use dataprovider in list view. So how can i use multiple dataprovider in Clist view?

Comment: Use only a dataProvider powered by a single query with joins.
Show the 'Yii relations'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple dataProviders to CListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451949/how-to-pass-multiple-dataproviders-to-clistview)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make use of multiple dataproviders rather you combine the result in a single dataprovider

Comment: Whats the solution for such a case?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to get you started:

```
public function actionSearch($q) {
    // Sanitize input
    $q = strtolower(strip_tags($q));
    $q = preg_replace('/[^a-z 0-9 _ \- \']/', '', $q);

    $model1 = Model1::model()->findAll('title LIKE "%'.$q.'%"');
    $model2 = Model2::model()->findAll('title LIKE "%'.$q.'%"');

    $rawData = array_merge($model1, $model2);
    $dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                 'datePublished DESC', 'title',
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('search', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'query' => $q,
    ));
}
```

Comment: When we can display data in  view file? if two models have different fields?