# Merging array outputs from database in Codeigniter, is this the way how it is done?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I figured a way how to combine two array outputs from a function in another function in the Codeigniter model class. It works well as I expected, but I suspect that this way is not the correct way.

```
public function get_job_detail($job_id){

    $this->db->from('jobs');
    $this->db->where('id', $job_id);
    $job_details = $this->db->get();

    $jobdetails = $job_details->row();
    $jobcompany = $this->get_company_details($jobdetails->company_id);

    $foo = array();

    foreach($jobdetails as $key=>$value){
        $foo[$key]=$value;
    }

    foreach ($jobcompany as $key => $value) {
        $foo[$key]=$value;
    }

        return $foo;
}

public function get_company_details($company_id){

    $this->db->from('companies');
    $this->db->where('id', $company_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();

}
```

So in the view page, I normally access the values by using the echo `$myvariable->xyz` but for some reason the return foo is not an object, therefore i had to access by using the array style `echo $myvariable['xyz']`. I have been looking around for answers but I couldn't find any (or maybe i am not using the correct keywords).

Is there suppose to be a correct way? or Codeigniter way to do this??

Many thanks!

Comment: I think this is your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('*')
    ->from('jobs')
    ->join('companies', 'companies.id=jobs.company_id', 'left');
```