# Merge 2 arrays of objects using php

Tags: php, object

I have 2 arrays that i don't know the name.

`foo: [{foo1: foo}, {foo2: fooo}]`
`bar: [{bar1: bar}, {bar2: barr}]`

and, using php, i need the output `myObject:{foo1: foo}, {foo2: fooo}, {bar1:bar}, {bar2:barr}`

Any ideas?

`public function searchNeighborhoods(Request $request) { if($request->has('cities')){ $data = []; $cities = $request->get('cities'); foreach($cities as $city){ $res = $this->client->request('GET', $this->url . "neighborhoods", ["query" => 'foo:bar' } return bag($data); }}`

Comment: Would be an idea to show your code

Comment: Duplicate of [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects)

Comment: merge arrays and convert it to object 
array_merge() and
(object)$arr;

Comment: @Option added the code