# Merge 2 Laravel query results in one object

Tags: php, laravel, object

I found a lot of similar questions but without a real solution for me.
I have a project on Laravel 5.4 
Now, in my Controller I am preparing filters for my search. 
So, Imagine that I want to filter my search by "location", and "about" fields of my `Cv` model.

So, I am finding distinct values of each one doing this

```
    $arrOfTags = explode(',', $request['position']);
 //separate basic search request(using some js modules that return a request with "," separator.
    //Basically, find a Cv where location of "positions" is distinct
    $filter0 = Cv::select('location')
                ->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags)
                ->groupBy('location')
                ->get();
    $filter1 = Cv::select('about')
                ->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags)
                ->groupBy('about')
                ->get();
```

Now, I want to concatinate this 2 results in object named `$filters`

And then, in my Blade to use it like :

```
@foreach($filters as $filter)
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="{{$filter->location}}"/> <span> {{$filter->location}} </span> </li> 
@endforeach

@foreach($filters as $filter)
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="{{$filter->about}}"/> <span> {{$filter->about}} </span> </li> 
@endforeach
```

I tried array_merge of objects, creating a new empty object and set parameters of this objects and other stuff, but without success.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects This worked for me :)

Comment: @VinayMulgund it returns me 
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /home/primo/jobiMarket/resources/views/filtersForSearch.blade.php)

That means that resultObject is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use [`unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-unique) collection method. Get the data:

```
$filters = Cv::select('location', 'about')
    ->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags)
    ->get();
```

Get unique values for each column and use results:

```
@foreach($filters->unique('location') as $filter)
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="location" value="{{ $filter->location }}"/> <span> {{$filter->location}} </span> </li> 
@endforeach

@foreach($filters->unique('about') as $filter)
    <li> <input type="checkbox" name="about" value="{{ $filter->about }}"/> <span> {{ $filter->about }} </span> </li> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Let me please get sure  that it works at expected, so did u understand me in the right way?
I already have an $request['position'], next I need to get all unique values of 'location', 'about' columns that belongs to 'positions'.

Example :  
$request['positions'] = "driver" ; So, I need to get all unique values of 'about' and 'location' from Cv model, where 'position' = driver

Comment: @priMo-ex3m I think I understood correctly. Please test this solution.

Comment: So, Imagine that I have 3 records in DB with table CV :
1)  position : 'driver', about : 'abcd', location : 'Albania' ;
2)  position : 'driver', about : 'dred' , location : 'Georgia' ;
3)  position : 'driver', about : 'dred' , location: 'Albania';

So, my filters must be : 
Country : Albania,  Georgia
About : abcd, dred

Comment: It works, thank you very much for the only correct solution!

Comment: Just one more question. Is there a way of concatinating 2 collections (like in my question example) into one result object?

Comment: @priMo-ex3m when you're using my code, you're executing only one query and get a single collection, so you don't need to concatenate it at all.

Comment: Yep, I perfectly understand that. I just want to know if it's possible and how in case I will need to use it (in another case,project). Thanks.

Comment: @priMo-ex3m you'll need to manually remap arrays or collections in this case. But it's a bad idea to do this anyway, you should use a single collection in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `merge` method to merge `two` collections. The merge method merges the given array or collection with the original collection. Try this-

```
    $filters =  $filter0->merge($filter1);
```

For further details you can see the official laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-merge)

Comment: It doesn't work. When I'm making {{$filters}} on view, it returns me htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /home/primo/jobiMarket/resources/views/filtersForSearch.blade.php)

That means that object is empty.

Comment: did you try foreach($filters as $filter)?? or you just print the whole collection??

Answer (score 0):

Why are you just making it complected ?

```
$locationFilters= Cv::select('location')
            ->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags)
            ->groupBy('location')
            ->get();

$aboutFilters= Cv::select('about')
            ->whereIn('position', $arrOfTags)
            ->groupBy('about')
            ->get();
return view('view name',compact('locationFilters','aboutFilters'));
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach($locationFilters as  $filter)
     <input value="{{$filter->location}}"/>
@endforeach

@foreach($aboutFilters as $filter)
     <input value="{{$filter->about}}"/>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

on the server side, you can do it as

```
$filters[] = $filter0->location;
$filters[] = $filter1->about;
```

on view, just print the value of the array instead of accessing the object.

Comment: I want to use OOP, that's why.