# How to merge more than one array, array comes from loop in php?

Tags: php

I need to merge a array, array are dynamic it may be 2,3,4 etc

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [orid] => 7
        [gid] => 13
        [user_id] => 3
        [rule_title] => test rule
        [event_data] => 
        [event_typ_id] => 0
        [rbid] => 9
        [tid] => 1
        [bundle] => 
        [etid] => 7
        [tagid] => 1
        [tag_name] => tag1
    )
    stdClass Object
    (
        [orid] => 7
        [gid] => 13
        [user_id] => 3
        [rule_title] => test rule
        [event_data] => 
        [event_typ_id] => 0
        [rbid] => 10
        [tid] => 2
        [bundle] => 
        [etid] => 7
        [tagid] => 2
        [tag_name] => tag2
    )
```

I have next array set .For such condition I cant use array_merge because it will
be merge all arrays. But I need to merge array object based on orid .

```
 stdClass Object
        (
            [orid] => 5
            [gid] => 13
            [user_id] => 3
            [rule_title] => test rule
            [event_data] => 
            [event_typ_id] => 0
            [rbid] => 9
            [tid] => 1
            [bundle] => 
            [etid] => 7
            [tagid] => 1
            [tag_name] => tag11
        )
        stdClass Object
        (
            [orid] => 5
            [gid] => 13
            [user_id] => 3
            [rule_title] => test rule
            [event_data] => 
            [event_typ_id] => 0
            [rbid] => 10
            [tid] => 2
            [bundle] => 
            [etid] => 7
            [tagid] => 2
            [tag_name] => tag12
        )
```

I need such type of array. Array will be based on orid. When new orid will be get then I need such type new array.Array will be dynamic it may be 2,3... etc.I am not getting how to merge these array values.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [orid] => 7
    [gid] => 13
    [user_id] => 3
    [rule_title] => test rule
    [event_data] => 
    [event_typ_id] => 0
    [rbid] => 9
    [tid] => 1
    [bundle] => 
    [etid] => 7
    [tagid] => 1
    [tag_name] => tag1 tag2 tag3
)



stdClass Object
    (
        [orid] => 5
        [gid] => 13
        [user_id] => 3
        [rule_title] => test rule
        [event_data] => 
        [event_typ_id] => 0
        [rbid] => 9
        [tid] => 1
        [bundle] => 
        [etid] => 7
        [tagid] => 1
        [tag_name] => tag11 tag12
    )
```

Comment: Thats not an array, thats an object. And by which criteria should it be merged?

Comment: joined the tag name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best method to merge two PHP objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects)

Comment: objects may be more than 2.

Comment: Does not matter. The merging in the article shown above can be written in a loop. That 's all you need.