# how to merge array? array_merge not working

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

hello everybody im trying to merge a a few array in an array.
currently with my code:

```
$matchs = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->get();
foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
    $array[] = [
        $match->date_access => $match->status,
    ];

}

dd($array);
```

so with this i get the ouput when i dd(); like:
[image]

so what i want to do now is to merge all that array to become one in array:16> 
 itself.
how can i do that? i have tried array merge and it isnt working either

Comment: Where are you using array_merge?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone inside the $array[]

Comment: i think this is object not array what framework you use ? 
if laravel eg. $merged = $collection->merge();
else 
https://gist.github.com/kkreft/9250494
or 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects

Comment: that's not `array_merge`, more like `array_push` ;p why not just do `$array[$match->date_access] = $match->status;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case you should have a unique `$match->date_access` so you can use it as a key of your array, like this :

```
$matchs = DiraChatLog::where('status','=','Match')
    ->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])
    ->get();

foreach ($matchs as $key => $match) {
    $array[$match->date_access] = $match->status;
}
```

if you have a more complex data you can use  [array_collapse](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-collapse) helper to collapses an array of arrays into a single array, 
here is an example :

```
$array = array_collapse([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]);

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: where exactly should i use this?