# Add an object to an existing variable into the object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, variables

I have a little problem, I'm in this situation: I have a json that I parse with no problems with json_decode making an object, in this array I have various values, in particular I have an array called "message" then I want to add values to this `$jsonObj->message` for example:

```
$jsonObj->message->hello = 'example';
```

now I want to add another object to `$jsonObj->message` without removing other values then, what I want is:

```
$jsonObj->message->hello; // this is auto generated from the json


$jsonObj->message ADD $json2;
```

So I should have `$jsonObj->message->somethingIntoJson2` and `$jsonObj->message->hello` too;

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with [What is the best method to merge two PHP objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455700/what-is-the-best-method-to-merge-two-php-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` to with the `true` as the second parameter to convert it to an array then you can assign a new index and its value and then use `json_encode`

```
$jsonArr = [
'mesage' => [
    'hello' => 'example'
 ]
];
$j   = json_encode($jsonArr);
echo $j;//{"mesage":{"hello":"example"}}
$obj = json_decode($j,true);
$obj['mesage']['element'] = 'value';
echo json_encode($obj);//{"mesage":{"hello":"example","element":"value"}}
```

Comment: Basically you suggest to modify everything as array and then convert to object?