# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error:array_push(): Argument #1($array) cannot be passed by reference in solution.php Stack trace in Merge Two Sorted Lists

Tags: php, arrays, oop, array-push

In the next question from [leetcode](/questions/tagged/leetcode): [the question_link](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/)

> You are given the heads of two sorted linked lists list1 and list2.
> Merge the two lists in a one sorted list. The list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.
> Return the head of the merged linked list.

And write the following code

```
/**
 * Definition for a singly-linked list.
 * class ListNode {
 *     public $val = 0;
 *     public $next = null;
 *     function __construct($val = 0, $next = null) {
 *         $this->val = $val;
 *         $this->next = $next;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    /**
     * @param ListNode $list1
     * @param ListNode $list2
     * @return ListNode
     */
    function mergeTwoLists($list1=[], $list2=[] ) {
         $count = (count((array)$list1) >= count((array)$list2)) ? count((array)$list1) : count((array)$list2);

       $list3[] = array();

        for ($i=0 ; $i < $count ; $i++){
            if(count((array)$list1) > $i){
                array_push( (array)$list3 , $list1[$i] );
            }
            if(count((array)$list2) > $i){
                array_push((array)$list3 , $list2[$i]  );
            }
        }

        return $list3;
    }
}
```

**gives this error**

```
Line 25: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) cannot be passed by reference in solution.php
Stack trace:
#0 solution.php: Solution->mergeTwoLists()
#1 {main}
```

You can also see an image of the error and the code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JslEr.png)

When deleting (array) from line 25 to be

```
        if(count((array)$list1) > $i){
              array_push( $list3 , $list1[$i] );
            }
```

**will give the error**

```
Line 25: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type ListNode as array in solution.php
Stack trace:
#0 solution.php: Solution->mergeTwoLists()
#1 {main}
```

**Screenshot with the error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s4fM.png)

Comment: Maybe change $list3[ ] = array( );

To

$list3 = [ ];

Comment: Why explicitly cast `$list3` as an array with `(array)$list3` when you are hardcoding it as an array?  I would never use `array_push()` to only push one value -- just use square brace pushing syntax: `$list3[] = $list1[$i]`

Comment: I don't play on leetcode.  Is there a reason why you don't simply merge list1 and list2 like `$list3 = array_merge($list1, $list2);`, then `sort($list3);`, then `return $list3;`????

Comment: If you are given objects but you want to work with arrays, then use `get_object_vars()`.

Comment: Relevant reading: [What is the best method to merge two PHP objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455700/2943403)

Comment: If you are not sure about what your input data is, then use `var_dump($variable)` to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

You must not explicitly cast the array (which is already hardcoded as an array) as an array inside of `array_push()`.

This is wrong: ([Simple Demo](https://3v4l.org/ULpOJ))

```
$array = [];
array_push((array) $array, 'test');
//         ^^^^^^^- bad
var_export($array);
```

Use this:

```
array_push($array, 'test');
```