# How to make a copy of an object without reference?

Tags: php, object, pass-by-reference

It is well documented that PHP5 OOP [objects are passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) by default. If this is by default, it seems to me there is a no-default way to copy with no reference, how??

```
function refObj($object){
    foreach($object as &$o){
        $o = 'this will change to ' . $o;
    }

    return $object;
}

$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->x = 'x';
$obj->y = 'y';

$x = $obj;

print_r($x)
// object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
//   ["x"]=> string(1) "x"
//   ["y"]=> string(1) "y"
// }

// $obj = refObj($obj); // no need to do this because
refObj($obj); // $obj is passed by reference

print_r($x)
// object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
//   ["x"]=> string(1) "this will change to x"
//   ["y"]=> string(1) "this will change to y"
// }
```

At this point I would like `$x` to be the original `$obj`, but of course it's not. Is there any simple way to do this or do I have to code something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119281/how-do-you-copy-a-php-object-into-a-different-object-type#answer-120758)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
<?php
$x = clone($obj);
```

So it should read like this:

```
<?php
function refObj($object){
    foreach($object as &$o){
        $o = 'this will change to ' . $o;
    }

    return $object;
}

$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->x = 'x';
$obj->y = 'y';

$x = clone($obj);

print_r($x)

refObj($obj); // $obj is passed by reference

print_r($x)
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful. lonesomeday makes a very good point about the `__clone()` magic method some classes might be implementing as well, which is worth noting.

Answer (score 30):

To make a copy of an object, you need to use [object cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

To do this in your example, do this:

```
$x = clone $obj;
```

Note that objects can define their own `clone` behaviour using `__clone()`, which might give you unexpected behaviour, so bear this in mind.

Comment: Thank you. You have some interesting info there.