# How to clone object to child class in php

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I have a parent class A, and child class B in PHP.
Is there any way to clone instance of class A to instance of B, and to use B class properties later in B instance?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: I don't think you can extend instances in real time if that is what you are asking. Consider giving more details about what you are trying to do though, perhaps there is another way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you copy a PHP object into a different object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119281/how-do-you-copy-a-php-object-into-a-different-object-type)

Comment: For those looking for answers to this question, here are the best answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958315/cannot-re-assign-this-use-reference-of-an-existing-object-a-into-another-objec

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My solution will be based on the solution from this question [How do you copy a PHP object into a different object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119281/how-do-you-copy-a-php-object-into-a-different-object-type)

```
class childClass extends parentClass
{
    private $a;
    private $b;

    function loadFromParentObj( $parentObj )
    {
        $objValues = get_object_vars($parentObj); // return array of object values
        foreach($objValues AS $key=>$value)
        {
             $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}

$myParent = new parentClass();
$myChild = new childClass();
$myChild->loadFromParentObj( $myParent );
```